# WxPython Feature Property Grid

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, propertygrid

I was wondering if a feature for WxPython existed or if I need to make it.

Here is a sample from a C# program I am trying to achieve with a property grid:
[Sample Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNy7.png)

I want this look with a checkbox in front of a PropertyCategory such as `Group 0` or `Message 0` in [PropertyCategoryExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajy1m.png) and can include the category. If you include the parent category I want the children categories to also be included.

Basically it acts as the expansion next to it but is a checkbox. I want to be able to still expand and shrink but just an extra checkbox when I go to save to see if the user wanted it included.

I have looked around in the docs and web but can’t find anything related to this. Do I need to make a custom property to do this?

I have asked on the discussion board but I haven't heard anything back

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl.html? Or maybe I misunderstood what you are looking for?

Comment: @Infinity77 Thank you for the suggestion! I didn't know about this class in wxpython. It is similar to what i need but would like to add the 'ct_type=1' (checkbox) to the PropertyCategory. I modified the post to reflect this.